# What is the easiest way to merge several PGP key files with gnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I have two key files `keys1.asc` and `keys2.asc` exported from my keyring, each containing several PGP public keys. What is the easiest way to merge them into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

One way that leads to the result, though probably not the easiest one:

```
% mkdir temp
% gpg --homedir temp --import keys1.asc keys2.asc
% gpg --homedir temp --armor --export >keys.asc
% rm -r temp
```